# Retrieve more than 2000 records with LookupRows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

What is the best way to retrieve more than 2000 records with the LookupRows AMPScript function?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [LookupOrderedRows](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/) function. You can set the number of rows returned through this feature. See below:

**LookupOrderedRows(S1, N1, S2, S3, S4)**

Returns a specified number of rows. You can specify multiple additional field/value pairs as part of an AND clause.

**Arguments**

`S1`    The name of the data extension from which to return the specified rows

`N1`    Number of rows to return. Any value less than 1 returns the default value of 2000 rows. This limitation helps enhance script performance.

`S2`    Order clause in the following format: field [asc | desc] [, ... ]

`S3`    Field to use to build the where clause

`S4`    Value to use to build the where clause